# Instantiate ViewModel from array items within an existing ViewModel.

Tags: javascript, arrays, mvvm, knockout.js

I've just started messing with knockout (tech requirement) and I'm trying to build a gallery with some custom functionality.

The data is coming from a `json` response that represents one gallery (title, description, etc) and within the gallery object, is an array of slides.

To try and separate concerns I'd love to have a gallery-based ViewModel and a separate slide ViewModel.

But I'm not sure how to instantiate the slide ViewModel on the array within the object.

In earlier version I tried to loop over the array of slides but not sure how I'd physical execute what I'm trying to do which is to set a new instance of the SlideViewModel on each `slide` object in the `slides` array

Any help is appreciate. Codepen here: http://codepen.io/pbj/pen/MaoLMb

Code here:

### JS

```
var testGallery = {
  "title" : "Anna's Gallery Title",
  "slides" : [
    {
      "title": "Slide Image #1",
      "image" : "http://google.com/image/goes/here"
    },
    {
      "title": "Slide Image #1",
      "image" : "http://google.com/image/goes/here"
    },
    {
      "title": "Slide Image #1",
      "image" : "http://google.com/image/goes/here"
    },
    {
      "title": "Slide Image #1",
      "image" : "http://google.com/image/goes/here"
    },
  ]
}

function GalleryViewModel(data) {
  // gallery functions
  this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
}

function SlideViewModel() {
 // slide functions here
 this.name = ko.observable(data.slides.title);
}

var gallery = new GalleryViewModel(testGallery);

ko.applyBindings(gallery);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be creating a child function of `slide` to achieve what you are looking at .

**viewModel:**

```
 function GalleryViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.title = ko.observable(data.title);
        self.caption = ko.observable(data.caption);
        self.slides = ko.observableArray();
        self.totalSlides = ko.observable(data.totalSlides);

        self.slides($.map(data.slides, function (n) { //mapping my child function in here
            return new slide(n);
        }))
    }

    function slide(data) { //child function
        this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
        this.image = ko.observable(data.image);
        this.position = ko.observable(data.position);
    }

var gallery = new GalleryViewModel(annasGallery);
ko.applyBindings(gallery);
```

working sample up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27179/)** for grabs

You can take help of **[mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)** which would be other way to do it in single line(as per your code)

**code:**

```
ko.applyBindings(ko.mapping.fromJS(annasGallery));
```

check the sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/LkqTU/27181/)** using mapping plugin

**PS:** As far i see nothing is editable you can bind plane js array to view (unnecessary usage of observable would turn costly )

Comment: This is great thank you! Part of the reason why most things are observable is because this will end up doing two things later: 

1. Adding new slides to existing gallery. 
2. seamlessly integrate new gallery (stitched effect). 

So the slides will need to be observable.

Comment: @patrick consider closing down this question by marking it as answer and upvote it . cheers